# How can unpersisting an RDD cause an RPC timeout?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a very large RDD that I am caching (it still fits into memory), but since it is so big, I want to unpersist it as soon as possible. However when I call unpersist on it, it is causing an RPC timeout error:

```
17/11/21 23:25:55 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 171
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeRdd(BlockManagerMaster.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.unpersistRDD(SparkContext.scala:1793)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.unpersist(RDD.scala:216)

17/11/21 23:27:55 WARN BlockManagerMaster: Failed to remove RDD 171 - Cannot receive any reply from null in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply from null in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
```

The code that is triggering this error looks like the following:

```
val tranformation1 = firstTransformation(inputData).cache
log("Tranformation1 Count: " + transformation1.count)
val transformation2 = secondTransformation(transformation1).cache
transformation1.unpersist()
```

Unpersisting an RDD should be a relatively inexpensive action. How can unpersisting an RDD cause an RPC timeout?

Comment: How large is “very large”? And which caching strategy is used?

Comment: @Ashalynd Nothing crazy. 16GB. The cluster is a 10 node cluster with 12 GB a piece. In the grand scheme of things it's not that big, but is by far the largest RDD that I am caching.

Comment: Are you sure it actually fit in memory? Otherwise it might be recompiling that RDD on the fly every time you try to access it, even for unpersist. To check that, you might try reducing the size of your data and see at which point this behavior kicks in.

Comment: @Ashalynd Yes. When I remove the `unpersist()` the RPC timeout goes away, and it shows 108% cached in the Storage tab of the Spark UI

Comment: @B.Smith did you figure it out?

Comment: @B.Smith were you able to resolve this? and what version of spark are you using just to confirm.

Comment: My issue is related, but I had difficulty search for it.  What is unpersist doesn't cause a timeout, but it just takes a really long time?  I've tried it with the default and with passing false as an argument, and still it seems to take a really long time.  This should probably be a different question, now that I'm thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more comprehensive answer as it is most likely a version dependent issue you are encountering - things have changed:

- See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26771?

  - Make .unpersist(), .destroy() consistently non-blocking by default

From the JIRA:

The RDD and DataFrame .unpersist() method, and Broadcast
.destroy() method, take an optional 'blocking' argument. The default **was**
'false' in all cases **except for (Scala) RDDs** and their GraphX subclasses.

The *default is now* ***'false'*** (non-blocking) in all of these methods.

Pyspark's RDD and Broadcast classes now have an optional 'blocking' argument as well, with
the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

unpersist() by default is blocking call, so it will wait for deletion of all the blocks of RDD. So once the instruction to unpersist the RDD is executed from driver it would ask all the executors to unpersist. Driver will wait to get the response from executors and executor may get timeout due to multiple reason like network issue.

To avoid the exception you can make unpersist() nonblocking and you would not receive this exception.

```
val tranformation1 = firstTransformation(inputData).cache
log("Tranformation1 Count: " + transformation1.count)
val transformation2 = secondTransformation(transformation1).cache
transformation1.unpersist(false)
```

On making the unpersist nonblocking, the RDD is just marked as deleted and it may get cleared during GC or background thread of Spark unpersist it.